# Need some help with shear stress

Tags: fluid-dynamics, aerodynamics

Just started getting into aerodyanamics/fluid dynamics and came across this paragraph.

In it, it explains how layer **a** exerts a frictional force on layer **b** due to a velocity gradient but it also says that we have to imagine an area **dA** that is *perpendicular* to the **y-axis**. I was wondering what exactly this meant or whether it matters at all i.e. does it mean that the area is *facing* in the direction of the **y-axis**?

I thought that didn't make sense because there would be no friction between the layers as the area of concern is **flat** so I was wondering if it meant that the *direction* that the area is facing is perpendicular to the **y-axis**.

I would appreciate any help! Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Yes, what they said is correct.  What area did you think the tangential frictional force was acting on?

Comment: An area that is perpendicular to the y direction is tangential to the surface of the body.

Comment: Oh ok. I thought that the frictional force was acting on the side of the fluid element that is parallel to y but this area was so small that it could be regarded as being tangential to the streamline.

Comment: y is perpendicular to a streamline, so an area can't be perpendicular to both y and perpendicular to a streamline.